# Custom Axis changing script not printing errors but not changing sizes

Tags: function, lua, roblox

I have this script which I supposedly want to make a custom axis and use it to change sizes. But its not printing errors however its not changing sizes. Here is my code (I will try to explain as much of it as possible below it.)

[image: 1]

```html
local w_axis1 = script.Parent["W axis #1"].Size.Z
local w_axis2 = script.Parent["W axis #2"].Size.Z
local w_axis3 = script.Parent["W axis #3"].Size.Z
local w_axis4 = script.Parent["W axis #4"].Size.Z
local x_axis = script.Parent.Xaxis.Size.X
local y_axis = script.Parent.Yaxis.Size.Y
local z_axis = script.Parent.Zaxis.Size.Z


function set_TesseractSize(w,x,y,z)
    
    w_axis1 = w
    w_axis2 = w
    w_axis3 = w
    w_axis4 = w
    x_axis =x
    y_axis =y
    z_axis =z
end

set_TesseractSize(70,15,7,10)
```

I am new to this so whenever I try to use code block only some of it is inside.
The Varibules are for easy access and getting the W axis to work.

What the function does is simple, you enter a number for each axis and that number is added to that object's size in that axis.
But it **does not change size**
Set_tesseractsize is the name of the function that sets each axis to its number.

I have tried:

- Changing the numbers around
- Checking to see if the sizes change in-game
- Checking if any of the W axis change positions/ go invisible.
  With this I know its something on my script, more on Roblox Studio because I think the problem is using "**(objname).Size.X**" there probably is another way.

Comment: Heyo, instead of sharing images of your code, could you copy and paste it as text? That way, it is easy for us to work with it.

Comment: You are changing local variables.  You should change object properties instead.

Comment: Still didn't work, I don't think the tesseract's parts being made out of unions effect it since it still has a size property with XYZ.

Comment: @Kylaaa Now its in a HTML snippet, the code block does not make lines and my whole code does not go inside.

Answer (score 0):

It does not change the size because you are just setting the variables, not the actual size of the Object. So you should either change the variables or just edit the set_TesseractSize function.